# Quorum with sidechains : Does Quorum work with sidechain blockchains?

Tags: blockchain, quorum, sidechain

I am currently working with quorum blockchain. Due to high number of transactions, there is a need to implement sidechain. Does quorum support sidechains?

Answer (score 0):

Quorum supports subchains rather than sidechains.
This is accomplished using enhanced permissioning model.
In Quorum terms; the blockchain can have organizations and suborganization, which reflects as subchains when implemented.